# Macbook Air reading wrong size and resolution of external monitor

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, vga-adapter, vga

I have LG Flatron E1941 which has a screen size of 18.5" and native resolution of 1366 x 768 but when connecting to my Macbook Air 2017(macOS Catalina) it is showing 13.9 inch and 800 x 600 resolution in System Preferences > Displays. I am unable to find the desired resolution under displays settings as well, tried switchresx as well, but the quality in the desired resolution is also not good.

[image]d.[image]

Comment: 1366 x 768  is just a really awkward resolution, & was used as a stop-gap between old 4:3 screens & modern 16:9. It's kind of an 'almost' 16:9 screen. It is probably failing to correctly report its information back to the Mac; perhaps a different cable might help. See https://superuser.com/questions/946086/why-does-1366x768-resolution-exist  for some background info.

Comment: It's got a pixel density of 85 pixels per inch, which is quite low, and it's only VGA input. So the image is always going to be a bit not good, even if you can get it full size.

Comment: thnx tetsujjin it is very old monitor ,i purchased it around 2011. This resolution is not available as standard on today's monitor. I will try to use a different cable to check if it works.